# can't overwrite reference with ant task using nested reference element

Tags: ant

I have a main build file with a path declaration

```
<path id="path.app.src">
  <pathelement location="myfolder/src"/>
</path>
```

Then i call a task in  sub file with `<ant>`

```
<ant antfile="subbuild.xml" inheritAll="false" inheritRefs="false">
    <reference refid="path.app.src"/>
</ant>
```

in subbuild.xml i have:

```
<path id="subpath.app.src">
  <pathelement location=".. some locations .."/>
  <path refid="path.app.src" />
</path>
```

In my understanding the call to `<ant>` with a nested  should overwrite path.app.src in subbuild.xml.

But i get an error like: subbuild.xml:xx: Reference path.app.src not found.

Am i doing something wrong ? is it a bug in ant ?

I'm using Apache Ant version 1.7.0 compiled on December 13 2006

Thanks,
Lionel

Answer (score 1):

in fact it seems to have the right behavior now, but i can't explain what i did wrong the first time.

here is the code sample:
build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="test" default="build" basedir=".">

    <path id="mainpath">
        <pathelement location="my/main/path"/>
    </path>

    <target name="build">
        <ant antfile="subbuild.xml" target="test">
            <reference refid="mainpath" torefid="globalpathid"/>
            <reference refid="mainpath" torefid="localtotargetpathid"/> 
        </ant>
    </target>    
</project>
```

subbuild.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="subbuild">

    <path id="globalpathid">
        <pathelement location="my/sub/location"/>
    </path>
    <target name="test">
        <path id="localtotargetpathid">
            <pathelement location="my/target/location"/>
        </path>
       <property name="p.localtotargetpathid" refid="localtotargetpathid" />

       <echo>p.localtotargetpathid: ${p.localtotargetpathid}</echo>

       <property name="p.globalpathid" refid="globalpathid" />

       <echo>p.globalpathid: ${p.globalpathid}</echo>

    </target>   
</project>
```

here is the console log:

```
$ ant
Buildfile: build.xml

build:
      [ant] Parent project doesn't contain any reference 'mainpath'

test:
     [echo] p.localtotargetpathid: d:\my\target\location
     [echo] p.globalpathid: d:\my\main\path

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

we can see `globalpathid` has been override but not `localtotargetpathid`, which is the behvior mentioned in the spec.

still I can't explain the first message ...

Comment: i meant the first message: [ant] Parent project doesn't contain any reference 'mainpath'

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an incomplete declaration here in the subbuild file of refid path.app.src.

```
<path id="subpath.app.src">
  <pathelement location=".. some locations .."/>
  <path refid="path.app.src" />   <=======
</path>
```

It should not have the 2nd nested path element () since there is no location associated with it. The way you wrote the main build file to overwrite no reference //other than// this refid looks good to me.